# Type '1' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a following function that takes a parameter of type T that extends Foo (which is an object). In the function, it iterates over each key of the given object to create a new object having exactly the same keys but the corresponding values are all 1 (what this function does does not really matter).

But it fails to compile with `Type '1' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'.`. I thought `T[Extract<keyof T, string>]` is  `number` so assigning `1` which is `number` should work.

What is wrong in my code?

```
type Foo = {
  [key: string]: number
}

const func = <T extends Foo>(obj: T): T => {
  for (const name in obj) {
    obj[name] = 1
  }
  return obj
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler will generally not do very sophisticated analysis of operations on generic types (that is, types which depend on an unresolved type parameter like `T` inside the implemenation of `func()`)... it tends to be better at dealing with concrete types (like `Foo`) which are more straightforward.

So the compiler is perfectly happy with and will allow the following concrete version of your function:

```
const concreteFunc = (obj: Foo): Foo => {
  for (const name in obj) {
    obj[name] = 1; // okay
  }
  return obj; // okay
};
```

Since an unresolved generic type isn't yet known, the compiler will be less certain that something you are doing is safe, and might issue a warning.  This warning doesn't necessarily mean that you have *definitely* made a mistake.

This situation often happens inside the implementation of generic functions.  If you carefully analyze what you are doing and decide that it is indeed type safe, you can use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to remove the warning.

For example, you can do this:

```
const func = <T extends Foo>(obj: T): T => {
  for (const name in obj) {
    obj[name] = 1 as T[typeof name]; // assert BUT BEWARE ☠
  }
  return obj;
};
```

But please note that a type assertion means that the responsibility for type safety has shifted from the compiler to you... and (to answer your question) *this is not safe*.

Here's why... consider the following code:

```
interface Bar extends Foo {
  two: 2;
  four: 4;
  six: 6;
  eight: 8;
}

const bar: Bar = {
  two: 2,
  four: 4,
  six: 6,
  eight: 8
};

const b = func(bar);

console.log(b.two); // 2 at compile time, but prints 1!
console.log(b.four); // 4 at compile time, but prints 1!
console.log(b.six); // 4 at compile time, but prints 1!
console.log(b.eight); // 4 at compile time, but prints 1!
```

Here we see an interface `Bar` which extends `Foo` by adding known properties whose values are [numeric literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types), none of which are equal to `1`. When we call `func(bar)`, `T` is inferred to be `Bar`, and thus the output of `func(bar)` is also supposed to be `Bar`.

And bad things happen.  We have an object whose known properties are supposedly even numbers at compile time, but actually the number `1` at runtime.

So that's why you probably shouldn't use assertions in a function like `func()`.  There might be an actually safe way to write `func()`... like, possibly this:

```
const funcSafer = <
  T extends { [K in keyof T]: 1 extends T[K] ? unknown : never }
>(
  obj: T
): T => {
  for (const name in obj) {
    obj[name] = 1 // error! still need "as T[typeof name]"
  }
  return obj;
};
```

Here, the constraint on `T` is specifically that `1` should be assignable to all its properties.  This has the following desirable effects:

```
funcSafer(bar); // error! property "two" is incompatible
const foo: Foo = {two: 2, four: 4}; // just Foo, not Bar
funcSafer(foo); // okay
funcSafer({a: 1 as 1}); // okay
funcSafer({a: 4}); // okay, interpreted as {a: number}
funcSafer({a: 4 as 4}); // error, "a" is incompatible
```

But of course, the compiler still can't tell that `obj[name] = 1` is safe inside the implementation.  It's just too complicated... so we need the assertion.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClA2gawhAC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwF1TaBXAWwCMJKBuLAL79MWAMZxaFKONqjKEYBBitZyKAAo4nAFal4cAJR6EyAHxosOAGZxKGmVNoBDdtDpQt2gxew4PO3GdXRjUARmEcAUsoeWBWSlp-bWEhLDEJKSsVUTUAHgAVKAgAD0VaABMyWARTTR1SfKMoQqRzDF8bO3UHYCggt0TPb3a-JMCXCBCUUKgnKvzcUEg4Kz6Jxl4oAHot2bIyHl6AIQBVQqOAUQB1AEEAJQuoQAIyaKjfWPjBnRThNMw6RSUKxOUTQI5OOwlMqVaqIEZQYAAdzgpAATBEoDZ4qQACwYsjUYqkABsGIg1HoAAtgKQABwpP49KCcCGkcF8dKSXqcNRZWTqFmUAy-TAOOAAGwgADpxXB6AKpUjDJsdlBUbNeuJ2GBqJKEdRXAAaZmsXpgGi0YBVUIAQk5ZAl0tl8s4UqxQpVuxxGukcG1uugwANEGNnFNUHNAOtdtFGUdMrlCoJxWF2y9Pq1Or1QaNJrNFqtUFt9vjzoV5KpwFTqu9Tk1fqzgeDofDkct0cZGV6fNEAGUnFYeHlooUoRAKlVUHgANJQdyEEArZrMItFUrjmELachAD8UBU+FocERiRYEAAbkO3rVop4Glgmi02tFOvYu2tXHOvl4fKNPONgjCT0ikoShbBtcgg3FcU+ggCByj2ZpFnACAl36DZXmiD4EiSH4-iwHt+0HSgBQhatdh4MDKAg804EgShQCgAAiJUmLnKo6EzOtqE4SV7W7BBjEQFBUCVNFjXdXEhDTKBtFYKR9GNI9jghAjsiInh1BsZUZLgfAnBANTZA0kjUCcUgZjmIsBHIjx9MMzBCIHTSzKk2y9IM40AR4c0FHgxDXL6DhuEoN4nOI9RAtrKocRs4DKNsY0mKcNjqA42QG243iID+IA)

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed explanation!
I wonder why it is complicated to know that `obj[name]` is of type `number`. It seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: We know that `obj[name]` is assignable to `number`, but we do *not* know that `number` is assignable to `obj[name]`.  So `const x: number = obj[name]` is fine, but `obj[name] = 1234` is not, because maybe the type of `obj[name]` is narrower than number.   That's what the `Bar` example shows.  `bar.two` is of type `2`, not `number`.  You can safely copy a value of type `2` into a variable of type `number`, but you can't safely copy a value of type `number` into a variable of type `2`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: > obj[name] is narrower than number

Ah, i see :) Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz so, type assertion is the only workaround for now? I understand that I know about the shape of the parameter more than the compiler does in such a case, but shouldn't it at least be able to infer that if a generic is constrained to, say, `{ [ P in keyof T ] : number }`, then a value of type `number` is assignable to `T[P]`. Is there a good reason why this is not the case?

Comment: The reason is the same as mentioned multiple times here: `T[P]` is assignable to `number`, but that does not mean `number` is assignable to `T[P]`.  Numeric literal types or unions of them are the canonical example of a type like this.