# "Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'" when using generics

Tags: typescript

I'm using generics in TypeScript (v4.5.4) and the following code throws an error:

```js
function foo<T extends Record<string, boolean>>(obj: T, key: string) {
    obj[key] = true; // ERROR: Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEHsFMGcDsDkAXUB3SAnA1gLgFABmArvAMbICWk8ohkkAPACqjQAey08AJrKACVoZLD0axkmSvADmAGlAAjBgBtoAQ3gA%20LQApIigFa5QzBdmgBPExKmyAlKADe%20AJAHDAbQuWAuqABeUEliaABufABffHwQUAB1LGxYAhF4CVAfG0lpGUDQREQItIyPEyERTDFbXIVlSDVNLXynSIiPbyt-IJDwoA)

This makes no sense to me whatsoever, it's even more nonsensical given the fact that the following actually works with no errors:

```js
const key: string = '';
const obj: Record<string, boolean> = {};
obj[key] = true; // NO ERROR
```

While as far I'm concerned the first code snippet is effectively doing the exact same thing.

I would like to know why this happens, and also how I could rectify the problem in the first snippet.

Comment: specify parameter `key` as type `keyof T` will get rid of your current error, but it also leads to another one (Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.(2322))... I would just cast `true` as `T[keyof T]`, @jcalz explains this pretty well in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56927160/14835397).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is a bug, which was discussed pretty deeply on GitHub. Here's the link: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47357