# Typescript: conditional generic Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to write a function with types (similar to the one at bottom) so that it can be used in the following ways. Either;

```js
parseApiResponse(apiResponse); // returns TParsedResponse
// or
parseApiResponse<TSpecificParsedResponse>(apiResponse); // returns TSpecificParsedResponse
```

where

```
type TApiResponse = {/* some complex non-specific raw data */}
type TParsedResponse = {[key:string]: string | number}[] // array of objects with any string as a key
type TSpecificParsedResponse = {name:string, age:number}[]
```

Here's my shoddy first attempt

```
const parseApiResponse = <T extends {}>(apiResponse: TApiResponse): T => {
  //some code here
  return parsedResponse;
};
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wk0D0w) work for you or am I missing something?  If it works I will write up an answer.

Comment: This is so great @jcalz and I think it has got me 99% of the way there, just like the other answer below! I've upvoted your answer thanks! But... When I have tried to create in practise I get an issue with the logic - please see this shorturl.at/dstET

Comment: Sorry, the above doesn't seem to work. tinyurl.com/2hd2x5bv

Comment: If the suggested solutions don't work for you, then you should [edit] your question to make your code a [mre] that demonstrates a situation where the proposed solutions fail.  It should be plain text in the question itself (although having an additional link to an IDE is a good supplement, it's not a substitute for the plain text).

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks and apologies, @jcalz. I did originally try to write it in the comment, but I didn't have enough characters. I now realise the issue was more fundamental to my logic so I'll post a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really good use case for `extends` in Typescript.

Here [is the full code example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=115&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKggmAlgJQgZzAewHZugXigG8oBjTAWzABsIAPALijWACdFsBzAGigHoAVM0rRyVWnSjYcAWgwRSiAGaJSUVgEMA7lAAmG4BqgC+AXwBQoSLAAKG1nl2oMOPFEJEA2gGsIIBizsXAC6TIEcnFAAPlIArhQARhCspp7B-HxQ9pogUJhKeQkAVgrAaFBaiMAAFlnYueFcWeVGviCW4NAwAMqQiiqkdg4QTuhYuATE2BoUEAFsEbwanHPY8UkpaeYd1hpIzuNuHhZKsdikwIg4UGD2eAgoY64QADwwUPTAENi65TBDjgOzwAfAAKPaPFwTJjwfZPCYASiI5igqIyUAAdFibqxMKR0GgUWjyLhgDc7iMgec5rB3FBPERTOkNH8iajWBBgLFWNhycNRlD8eYLOYSSwPnQZjQIAB5AByk1uwweVLwoKIYmljCgAHIlJhMDrTAiANzojlcnl-AGU+F4cx8TKYVii1xk+hS2gwLSYOlK+5wqF4N69BTKVQ2gWHCBgjWULVMPUGo2m82c7m4WCh-oRilR55AA)

The main idea is that have a generic type that extends the base type.

```js
function parseApiResponse<T extends TParsedResponse>(apiResponse: TApiResponse){
    // ... process
    const parsedResponce: T = [{}] as T
    return parsedResponce
}
```

Typescript will infer the "extended" type if it is not passed and will use the more specify one if it is passed.

Here is the full code example in case the Playground link above does not work.

```
type TParsedResponse = {[key:string]: string | number}[] // array of objects with any string as a key
type TSpecificParsedResponse = {name:string, age:number}[]

function parseApiResponse<T extends TParsedResponse>(apiResponse: TApiResponse){
    // ... process
    const parsedResponce: T = [{}] as T
    return parsedResponce
}

const exampleOne = parseApiResponse({complex: 'foo'}); // returns TParsedResponse
// or
const exampleTwo = parseApiResponse<TSpecificParsedResponse>({complex: 'foo'}); // returns TSpecificParsedResponse
```

Comment: Honestly, this is so good and I think it has got me 99% of the way there! I've upvoted your answer thanks! But...

When I have tried to create in practise I get an issue with the logic - please see this shorturl.at/dstET

Comment: Sorry, the above doesn't seem to work. tinyurl.com/2hd2x5bv

Comment: @moroncodes it seems like typescript compiler is not super sophisticated when it comes to iterating over generic types (see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56925857/type-1-is-not-assignable-to-type-textractkeyof-t-string) ). That being said I was able to fix your example by adding another generic to the data type.

See: tinyurl.com/5wepe8e2 for more information.